# recursive permutation combination

Tags: t-sql

i need help achieving the following output.
i have a table

```
declare @tblLevels  table(
levelsID                INT IDENTITY(1,1),
levelNumber             INT,
levelDesc               VARCHAR(100))
insert into @tblLevels(levelNumber,levelDescription)
 values 
(1,'L1D1'),
(1,'L1D2'),
(1,'L1D3'),
(1,'L1D4'),
(2,'L2D1'),
(2,'L2D2'),
(2,'L2D3'),
(2,'L2D4'),
(3,'L3D1'),
(3,'L3D2'),
(3,'L3D3')

select * from @tblLevels

levelsID    levelNumber levelDesc
========================================
1               1           L1D1
2               1           L1D2
3               1           L1D3
4               1           L1D4
5               2           L2D1
6               2           L2D2
7               2           L2D3
8               2           L2D4
9               3           L3D1
10              3           L3D2
11              3           L3D3
```

i have another table(@tblLevelSpreadOut) whose structure goes as below

```
declare @tblLevelSpreadOut  table(
levelSpreadOutID                INT IDENTITY(1,1),
levelNumber1                    INT,
levelDesc1                      VARCHAR(100),
levelNumber2                    INT,
levelDesc2                      VARCHAR(100),
levelNumber3                    INT,
levelDesc3                      VARCHAR(100))
```

it needs to be populated from the former table(@tblLevels), such that the output is

```
    select  levelNumber1, levelDesc1,  levelNumber2 ,levelDesc2 , levelNumber3 ,levelDesc3 
from @tblLevelSpreadOut

 levelNumber1 levelDesc1  levelNumber2 levelDesc2  levelNumber3 levelDesc3
============================================================================
1   L1D1    2   L2D1    3   L3D1
1   L1D1    2   L2D1    3   L3D2
1   L1D1    2   L2D1    3   L3D3
1   L1D1    2   L2D2    3   L3D1
1   L1D1    2   L2D2    3   L3D2
1   L1D1    2   L2D2    3   L3D3
1   L1D1    2   L2D3    3   L3D1
1   L1D1    2   L2D3    3   L3D2
1   L1D1    2   L2D3    3   L3D3
1   L1D1    2   L2D4    3   L3D1
1   L1D1    2   L2D4    3   L3D2
1   L1D1    2   L2D4    3   L3D3
1   L1D2    2   L2D1    3   L3D1
1   L1D2    2   L2D1    3   L3D2
1   L1D2    2   L2D1    3   L3D3
1   L1D2    2   L2D2    3   L3D1
1   L1D2    2   L2D2    3   L3D2
1   L1D2    2   L2D2    3   L3D3
1   L1D2    2   L2D3    3   L3D1
1   L1D2    2   L2D3    3   L3D2
1   L1D2    2   L2D3    3   L3D3
1   L1D2    2   L2D4    3   L3D1
1   L1D2    2   L2D4    3   L3D2
1   L1D2    2   L2D4    3   L3D3
1   L1D3    2   L2D1    3   L3D1
1   L1D3    2   L2D1    3   L3D2
1   L1D3    2   L2D1    3   L3D3
1   L1D3    2   L2D2    3   L3D1
1   L1D3    2   L2D2    3   L3D2
1   L1D3    2   L2D2    3   L3D3
1   L1D3    2   L2D3    3   L3D1
1   L1D3    2   L2D3    3   L3D2
1   L1D3    2   L2D3    3   L3D3
1   L1D3    2   L2D4    3   L3D1
1   L1D3    2   L2D4    3   L3D2
1   L1D3    2   L2D4    3   L3D3
```

thanks to all who replied and also to all who viewed the issue.

Comment: 4 words:
what
have
you tried ?

Comment: to all those who have a grudge against me, not accepting answers -- it was a mistake on my side. would do in future.

Comment: ElVieejo -- i didnt want to go the cursor way. thus am trying it out with LEFT OUTER JOINS.

Comment: CocaCola, you can always go back and accept your answers now, you haven't lost any opportunities.

Answer (score -1):

You want a full outer join?

Try

```
select  
 t.levelNumber1, 
 t.levelDesc1,  
 t.levelNumber2 ,
 t.levelDesc2 , 
 t.levelNumber3 ,
 t.levelDesc3 
from 
 @tblLevelSpreadOut t outer join
 @tblLevelSpreadOut t2
order by
 t.levelDesc1,  
 t.levelDesc2 , 
 t.levelDesc3
```

Also, consider accepting answers to your questions.  You'll get better responses from the community.

Comment: i think u misinterpreted my question Beth. the SELECT statement has to be on tblLevels, such that tblLevelSpreadOut gets populated with data as shown above. eg :-                                                                         levelNumber1 levelDesc1  levelNumber2 levelDesc2  levelNumber3 levelDesc3
===================================================================
1   L1D1    2   L2D1    3   L3D1
1   L1D1    2   L2D1    3   L3D2